# Can one say Kaddish for a deceased family member even if their parents are still alive?

Tags: halacha, death, kaddish

If a family member dies without leaving any children to say Kaddish for them, can another family member take on the job of saying Kaddish?  Is it permissible even if the parents of the one saying it are still alive?

I know that some people do not say the Mourner's Kaddish if both of their parents are alive.  I am not certain if this is just a custom, or if it is actually forbidden to. If the parents do not object, then why would there be any problem with anyone Sanctifying the Name?  *Someone* should say it for a Jew, right?

Comment: @DanF, no. My question is not related to the existence of deceased relatives. IIR my question question properly, this is not a dupe.

Comment: @NoachmiFrankfurt "existence of deceased relatives" - Huh??? If they're deceased, how can they exist??? (OK, I know what you meant ;-) Seriously, I don't see the difference between this question and yours. What did I miss?

Comment: @DanF, that question appears to be particularly about resolving a difference between one's parents and one's rabbi.

Comment: @IsaacMoses, if the question isn't a duplicate, then the answer on the other question needs to be deleted and the phrase at the end of that question that justified the answer modified to not mislead future answers about the intention of the question.

Comment: @Yishai, I agreee that that answer doesn't answer the question. I've voted to close that question, since, despite the disclaimer, it's asking "what should I do in my specific situation?"

Answer (score 2):

If one's parents give permission for one to do so, then one may. For example, I was asked by my mother to say kaddish for an aunt who died without any children. However, if the parents object, then it is a matter of Kibud Av Ve'Aim (honoring one's parents) because they could regard it as expressing a wish that for them to die. As seen in the sources, it is a requirement that the parents agree before one starts saying the kaddish.

When the parents do consent, it can be considered that one is honoring his parents by doing this. in their stead.

[Can I say kaddish for someone if my parents are still alive?](http://www.askmoses.com/en/article/165,73275/Can-I-say-kaddish-for-someone-if-my-parents-are-still-alive.html)

> Rabbi Latowicz: if no one else available, and the grandchild's parents consent... then it is ok

[Saying Kaddish for a Person Who Does Not Have an Adult Son](http://ph.yhb.org.il/en/03-04-08/)

> The grandson and son-in-law are permitted to say Kaddish only when one
>   of their own parents is deceased, **or if their parents agree to his
>   reciting Kaddish while they are living. However, someone whose parents are strict that he not say Kaddish while they are both alive may not recite the Kaddish for his grandparent or in-law.**

Comment: A local rabbi in Chicago disallows doing this even with the parents' permission

Comment: Parents who don't give permission should really just get over themselves and let the kid do something nice. What kind of chinukh is that anyway? That your own ego and fear of a child's conspiracy against you outweighs chesed shel emet?

Comment: @DoubleAA What the parent should do is not part of the question. If the parent believes that the child saying kaddish for the relative will cause him to **have to say kaddish for the parent** (as some people do), then it is an actual sakannah (in the parent's mind). However, that is not part of this question.

Comment: @sabbahillel Indeed it is not part of the question. You should know though that just bc a parent believes something doesn't make it a sakana. It is not a sakana. Skipping this opportunity is the same as if your parents told you not to jump rope. You listen because they said so not because they're being even slightly reasonable.

Comment: @DoubleAA I edited it to say that the parent fully believes that it is a sakanah

Comment: @sabbahillel I don't know how that helps anything...

Comment: @sabbahillel do you know if the child has to re-ask the parents if, years later, another situation arises? Or does a single permission stay in effect?

Comment: @rosends I would guess that it is better to ask again as circumstances can change